# @foreach Not Repeat Same Value (razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have some data from database:

```
Type   | Name
----------------
Fruit  | Apple
Fruit  | Manggo
Flower | Rose
```

I want in view in cshtml

```
Fruit  | Apple  

       | Manggo

Flower |Rose
```

i already make code

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
      <th>@item.Type</th>
    </tr>

    foreach(var items in Model)
    {    
      <tr>
          <td>@items.Name</td>
      </tr>    
    }     
}
```

But wrong ..

Comment: can you provide model class?

Comment: LINQ and SQL both allow you to group by values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your inner loop, get the items that have the same type as the item in the outer loop:

```
foreach(var items in Model.Where(i => i.Type == item.Type)){
```

Alternatively, group the items:

```
@foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(i => i.Type))
 {
  <tr>
  <th>@group.Key</th>
  </tr>

 foreach(var item in group){

    <tr>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
    </tr>

    } 

 }
```

Comment: Help me to implement my logic.

Answer (score 1):

both your `foreach` loops are looping through the model.  Your inner `foreach` should loop through the outer, as you have a nested collection:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
 {
     foreach(var innerItem in item){

     } 
 }
```

Comment: I don't think it is gonna work.Item is probably a single item, instead of collection of items.

Comment: Yeah, if you aren't using nested collections, go with @Guffa's answer